# How to hide / show the content of a component that is reused by different views in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have two views that call a particular component and this makes it difficult for me to hide / show when the component is needed. In this way, I have the following:

I tried to make a display: none to overide the styles but it is a problem. This is because the views when using the same component, the classes of the CSS are called the same and when I make the display: none, I get it not to show in "News" but in "Home" it also affects and it is not shown to me.

I tried it:

**Component Section:**

```
      <div className="section_news">
        {orden.map(this.renderSection)}
        <ViewAllNews mostrarCategorias={false} categoriaId={newsId} />
```

If I remove the title like this, I'll leave the view "Home" and "News", and that's not what I intend to do.

Next, I leave the original piece of code:

**View named "Home":**

```
<div className="contentbar">
      <Section title="Ult. News" />
      <Section
        notices_id={19}
        orden={[[0, 3], [3, 1], [4, 2]]}
      />
    </div>
```

**View named "News": **

```
   <Section
        notices_id={data.post.category.id}
        orden={[[0, 2], [2, 3]]}
      />
```

**Component Section:**

```
      <div className="section_news">
        <Titles title={title || (category && category.title)} />
        {orden.map(this.renderSection)}
        <ViewAllNews categoriaId={newsId} />
```

**Component ViewAllNews:**

```
  return (
    <Link to={`/news/c/${categoryId}/`}>
      <div className="parentLineViewAll">
        <div className="LineViewAll" />
        <div className="line" />
        <div className="Views">View All</div>
        <div className="arrowMore">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-circle-right" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

As you can see, the view of **"Home"** and **"Views"** make use of the same component.

What I really need is to hide the component named  for the **"News" view** and also hide the **"ViewAllNews" component** only for the **"News" view.**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to hide / show react components is to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Here is a basic example:

```
class MyComponent Extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false, // <-- add a value to state so we can track the components visibility
    }
  }

  show = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: false })
  }

  hide = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true })
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.isVisible){
      return (
       /* your component code */
      )
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to toggle the component from inside a parent component then you can control this with a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
class Parent Extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }

  render(){
    return <MyComponent ref={this.myRef}>
  }
}
```

Once the component mounts, you can check if the ref has been set and call the method anywhere in your code:

```
if(this.myRef.current){
  this.myRef.current.show() // or .hide()
}
```

You can also control the components visibility via props:

```
function MyComponent({ isVisible }){
  if(isVisible){
    return (
      /* your component code */
    )
  }
}
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: How can I send the isVisible from my home component to get the value to the Section component? I mention it because it is not coming to me and it is necessary that Section receives "isVisible" from any view to hide / show

Comment: That's entirely up to you, I'm not sure what you mean. You pass props like this `<MyComponent isVisible={someValue}>`

Comment: I do that, but when I receive it in my Section component, the value that I sent from the view **"Home"** does not arrive

Comment: I really have achieved it with your help. I regret the previous question, it was frustrating me already haha. Thank you very much, you have been very helpful!

Comment: One last question. In the component I am putting as you mentioned it to me: if (props.isVisible === 1) ... however, if I do not return null, I get an error "Nothing was returned from this. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null. "

Comment: ah yeah I left that out, just add `else return null` to your if statement

Answer (score 0):

a way to implement this `componentWillUnmount()` and `componentWillMount()` , 
like to [this example](https://codepen.io/baldwmic/pen/bwzPxp) , hope help you this.